# The property 'Cod' of type 'X' cannot use element name '_id' because it is already being used by property 'Cod'

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have been creating a website with mongo a c# driver. I have created this class for storing my data:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class STT_Hotel
{
    public class STT_Hotel_Id
    {
        [BsonElement("prov_id")]
        [JsonProperty("prov_id")]
        public int provid { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("property_id")]
        [JsonProperty("property_id")]
        public string PropertyId { get; set; }

    }

    [BsonId]
    [BsonElement("id")]
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public STT_Hotel_Id Cod { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

when I am serializing, it is correctly saved into the database.

The problem comes when I try to get the object, I got the exception:

> The property 'Cod' of type 'STT_Hotel' cannot use element name '_id' because it is already being used by property 'Cod'.

have been searching but no idea why.

I have deleted all the data of the collection and still having the same issue

Comment: I don't know, but is it possible that `[BsonId]` and `[BsonElement("id")]` are the same thing?

Comment: I have just tried with                      [BsonId]
        public STT_Hotel_Id Cod { get; set; } and got the same restult

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself, it turns out that I had a tag with the same element name twice:

```
   [BsonElement("images")]
    [JsonProperty("images")]
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("images")]
    [JsonProperty("images")]
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
```

that was causing the issue.

Comment: Awsome I had exactly the same problem, BsonElement attribute was defined twice.
Thanks for your help !